# How to have a program open with Compiz "put right"?

Tags: compiz

When I open my text editor, I always use a keyboard shortcut to "put right" through the compiz window-snapping feature.

Is there a way I can make this single program always automatically open that way, and put itself there?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put right"? Can you post a screenshot of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using "Place Window" plugin in ccsm. By adding your program in windows in fixed position you can control the position of your program. You need to give the x,y co-ordinate. (x,y)=(0,0) in left-upper corner of the screen. Xmax= your x axis resulation's. As an example if your screen resulation in 1024x768 then Xmax=1024 and Ymax=768.

[image]